# Find out the processes or scripts updating a file Solaris

Tags: file, unix, solaris

I have a log file which captures the file transfer details from my server like rsh, sftp, ssh session details. I just want to backtrack and find out what all are the processes/scripts updating the log files. I am not quite sure how this information is captured.

The log file looks like:

```
Oct 15 11:43:35 myclient inetd[15032]: [ID 927837 daemon.info] connect from client22.mydomain.com
Oct 15 11:43:35 myclient inetd[15033]: [ID 927837 daemon.info] connect from Client101.mydomain.com
Oct 15 11:43:35 myclient inetd[15034]: [ID 927837 daemon.info] connect from client05dev.mydomain.com
Oct 15 11:43:36 myclient inetd[15038]: [ID 927837 daemon.info] connect from searay.mydomain.com
Oct 15 11:43:36 myclient in.rshd[15038]: [ID 724835 daemon.info] connect from epsadmin@searay.mydomain.com (ls -l /home/generic/fpcdetail/fpcdetail.bod.mm)
Oct 15 11:43:36 myclient inetd[15041]: [ID 927837 daemon.info] connect from pgdbsu01dev.mydomain.com
Oct 15 11:43:36 myclient in.rshd[15041]: [ID 724835 daemon.info] connect from qrtdev@pgdbsu01dev.mydomain.com (ls -l /ifeeds/filemgr/filemgr.rimes.ftspeuro_industry_prn)
Oct 15 11:43:36 myclient inetd[15040]: [ID 927837 daemon.info] connect from client22.mydomain.com
Oct 15 11:43:38 myclient inetd[15044]: [ID 927837 daemon.info] connect from client22.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 2):

That looks like syslog output. If that's the case, then you're going to find that the only process touching the logfile is `syslogd`. The programs use [`syslog(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog) to perform the logging. In general, the name e.g. `inetd[12345]` is the name and process id of the program that performed the logging.

As you're using solaris, you can use dtrace to see who's invoking syslog - see [this dtrace one-liner](https://blogs.oracle.com/chrisg/entry/on_this_interweb_thingy) for something similar to what you're looking for; but it is limited to the once pid that is being traced.